# CSS images next to links - more specific?

Tags: css, image, hyperlink

I am using something like this:

```
.entry a {
  padding: 2px 0 0 8px;
  background: transparent url(images/link_arrow_light.gif) left top no-repeat;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Which works fine but adds that image to all links (images, h3 tags, ...)

Is there a css way to have it only appear besides links that are within p-tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.entry p a {
```

This forces the `<a>`s to be a descendent of a `<p>` (while the `<p>`s must also be descent of some tags with the class `entry`.)

Comment: Simple but couldn't think of this.

Comment: But images still have the image. .entry p a img {background:none;} didn't work? thanks

Comment: @Julian: Unfortunately, that's not possible with CSS alone. You can to add a class to those `<a>` with `<img>` and set the `background:none` for those class.

Comment: The background image will appear on the <a> that wraps an <img>, not on the image itself. That is why your suggestion above didn't work. Do you not have access to the html? If you do just add a class to links that wrap an image and the set that class to have no background